# calculate descriptives for a nested variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to calculate the M, min, and max of a variable. Data were collected at different visits. My data look like this:

```
id   visit     V1    
1     1        18
1     2        24
2     2        NA
2     3        5
2     4        6
```

I want it to look like this, where I have columns for the M, SD, min, and max for V1 for each participant.

```
id   visit     V1    M      MIN    MAX
1     1        18    21     18     24      
2     2        3     4.67    3     6
```

In calculating the M, I want to take into account the # of visits (e.g., 18 + 24/2 visits). I tried this as a first step:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(M = mean(V1), MIN = min(V1), MAX = max(V1), na.rm = T)
```

When I try to handle the NAs by making sure they are not included, the na.rm = T results in a new column entitled "na.rm" with every value being true, which isn't what I want. Any thoughts on making this work?

Comment: You can try `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(M=mean(V1),Min=min(V1),Max=max(V1))` with `df` being your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dplyr` package makes this easy. You can `group_by()` a variable, and whatever you do after that only applies within the group. In `dplyr` notation, the `%>%` is a special operator that feeds the outcome of the function on the left into the first argument of the function on the right.

There are two ways to do it. The first way keeps all of the data, but your summary statistics are repeated in each row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(M = mean(V1), MIN = min(V1), MAX = max(V1)
id   visit     V1    M      MIN    MAX
1     1        18    21     18     24      
1     2        24    21     18     24
2     2        3     4.67    3     6
2     3        5     4.67    3     6
2     4        6     4.67    3     6
```

The second way provides only the summary statistics by the group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(M = mean(V1), MIN = min(V1), MAX = max(V1)
id   M      MIN    MAX
1    21     18     24      
2    4.67   3      6
```

Comment: hey @Ben Norris. I decided to use the second piece of code you provided as I think that's more in line with what I want. However, the code seems to be providing the M, MIN, and MAX of that specific variable for everyone. Do you have suggestions for revising?

Comment: You may need to add additional variables to `group_by` to get more granular statistics

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: R seems to be choking on the NAs and is not giving me the descriptives I need. I modified my code to reflect what you did (see above), but added na.rm = T, but that isn't doing the trick. Any advice? Thanks so much fo your help. :)

Comment: You need to put `na.rm = TRUE` into each function: `mean(V1, na.rm = TRUE)`, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Ben! I'm still learning R so I really appreciate your patience and your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `dplyr` approach similar to @ThomasIsCoding that produces something similar to what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), visit = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), V1 = c(18L, 24L, 3L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

The code:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(M=mean(V1),Min=min(V1),Max=max(V1),SD=sd(V1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
     id visit    V1     M   Min   Max    SD
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1     1    18 21       18    24  4.24
2     1     2    24 21       18    24  4.24
3     2     2     3  4.67     3     6  1.53
4     2     3     5  4.67     3     6  1.53
5     2     4     6  4.67     3     6  1.53
```

Comment: @D.Fowler Great it helped you!!! Nice coding for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like below

```
transform(df,
  M = ave(V1, id, FUN = mean),
  MIN = ave(V1, id, FUN = min),
  MAX = ave(V1, id, FUN = max)
)
```

which gives

```
  id visit V1         M MIN MAX
1  1     1 18 21.000000  18  24
2  1     2 24 21.000000  18  24
3  2     2  3  4.666667   3   6
4  2     3  5  4.666667   3   6
5  2     4  6  4.666667   3   6
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), visit = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), V1 = c(18L, 24L, 3L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```